# In firebase realtime database can the key start with a capital letter?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Can the stocks child node (Adani Green Energy Ltd) have spaces and start with a capital letter and also its child nodes (CompanyType, DividendYield, MarketCap) start with a capital letter or is it a condition to start it with a small letter? I want to retrieve this data in recycler view but I am unable to do so. Can this be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits#data_tree) is clear what the valid characters are:

> Keys are UTF-8 encoded and can't contain new lines or any of the following characters:
> . $ # [ ] / or any ASCII control characters (0x00 - 0x1F and 0x7F)

Capital letters are not forbidden from this list.  If they were, you would not have been able to create the nodes in the first place.